# IIS 7 metabase: Setting the framework version and the managed pipeline mode programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7, iis-metabase

How can I set the ehe **.net framework version** and the **managed pipeline mode** programmatically for a IIS 7 programmatic via C#? What a the metabase property names for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration%28VS.90%29.aspx) assembly. Here's how you could set the framework version:

```
using (var manager = new ServerManager())
{
    // Get the web site given its unique id
    var site = manager.Sites.Cast<Site>().Where(s => s.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (site == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The site with ID = 1 doesn't exist");
    }

    // get the application you want to set the framework version to
    var application = site.Applications["/vDirName"];
    if (application == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The virtual directory /vDirName doesn't exist");
    }

    // get the corresponding application pool
    var applicationPool = manager.ApplicationPools
        .Cast<Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool>()
        .Where(appPool => appPool.Name == application.ApplicationPoolName)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (applicationPool == null)
    {
        // normally this should never happen
        throw new Exception("The virtual directory /vDirName doesn't have an associated application pool");
    }

    applicationPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0.30319";
    manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

And here's how to set the managed pipeline mode to integrated:

```
using (var manager = new ServerManager())
{
    // Get the application pool given its name
    var appPool = manager.ApplicationPools["AppPoolName"];
    if (appPool == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The application pool AppPoolName doesn't exist");
    }

    // set the managed pipeline mode
    appPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;

    // save
    manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But because of some reasons I cannot use Microsoft.Web.Administration. I must do it with DirectoryEntry

Comment: I am developing under Windows XP, but the software is running on a Windows 2008 server. Nevertheless, I have already found the solution for myself.